# schemamigration/refactor model using south

Tags: django, django-south

I have model `Foo` which resides inside app `bar`. Now, I wish to move thmodel to app `bar2`. I am already using `db_table` when `syncdb` with `bar` before

```
meta:
   db_table = 'foo_table'
```

Now when I do schemamigration with `bar`, south wants me to delete the table. Is there any ways I can avoid this (table name `foo_table` is still the same despite changing the app) without manually editing the migration file?

Comment: What's wrong with editing the migration file? South does pretty well most of the time, but in cases like this, it sometimes fails to determine the best course of action. Generate the migration, remove the delete table action, migrate, and your done. It won't try to remove it again.

Comment: Im suppose that might do.. anw just realize that there are stuff like contenttype entries that needs to be taken care of too ...

Answer (score 0):

if no changes in database, then you can create empty migrations for both apps in which was this model and which now has this model:

```
./manage.py schemamigration app1 del_model1 --empty
./manage.py schemamigration app2 add_model1 --empty
```

south analyze models which described in last migration and on this data he create next migrations